# Online Out-of-Core Logistic Regression with TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, large-data

I'm currently trying to use TensorFlow (particularly the [tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LinearClassifier) estimator) to train an Online Logistic Regression:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=1.0,initial_accumulator_value=0.4)
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(model_dir=model_dir,
                                      feature_columns=wide_columns,
                                      optimizer=optimizer)


m.partial_fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train),batch_size=1)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

`ValueError: Can not provide both input_fn and batch_size.`

It looks like the batch_size argument has been deprecated. Is anyone aware of any simple way to perform online learning in that case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the document

> Arguments x, y and batch_size are only available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn. Example conversion: est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))

Try with [`tf.contrib.learn.SKCompat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/SKCompat)